# How can I validate and convert an input to a single digit (int) in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm learning C++ and this is my code:

```
int val1,val2;
char op;
cout << "Please enter a calculation (operand operator operand):";
cin >> val1 >> op >> val2;
if((val1<0||val1>9)||(val2<0||val2>9)) {
    cout << "Operand must be between 0 and 10!" << endl;
}
cout << "val1: " << val1 << "  val2: " << val2 << endl;
```

The validation works but I still haven't just one digit in the variable val1 or val2 if I enter for example 34+56.

I want to end up with an error message for a number that has 2 digits or more and I want to have only one digit in the variables val1 and val2.

I tried working with chars, strings and isdigit() but I'm still in the dark here.  Thx for the help!!

Comment: Not getting the same error. I was getting a compiler error at first because you're missing a `;` after your first `cout`, but it's giving me the correct error message.

Comment: So you want the user to enter expressions until validation is OK? Or do you just want to "correct" he invalid input, e.g. by taking only the least significant digit (i.e. `val1 = val1%10`)?

Comment: Please state the actual problem, `(val1<0||val1>9)||(val2<0||val2>9)` will evaluate to false if either operand is 0 but not 10 or any negative which is not consistent with "Operand must be between 0 and 10!" or the title. Also "I want to end up with an error message for a number that has 2 digits or more and I want to have only one digit in the variables val1 and val2." doesn't really make sense, we use multiple digits to represent natural numbers for a reason, they cannot all be magically compressed to single digit representations.

Comment: @jmoon: Thx, it was a typo.

Comment: @Schwifty: I'm still learning C++ so I want to try to end up with variables (ints) that contain only the first digit of the number that was inputted.  For example, if I enter 3457 I want 3 to be in val1.

Comment: @m3n741 Ah ok, you can just divide the input through to get the most significant digit :) `while( val1 > 9 ) val1 /= 10;` (you'll still need to handle the case `val1 < 1`, to get the absolute value of `val1`, you could say `if(val1 < 1) val1 *= -1;`)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main(){
    int x = 100;
    std::cout <<  std::to_string(x)[0] - '0';

}
```

okay that's fine. first digit in the number. I have c++11 solution.
while compiling add compiler flag `-std=c++11`

Comment: Thx crook, but what if I want to convert val1 with a value 345 to an int that has value 3?

Comment: I used the c++11 flag but cout didn't output anything.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd like to suggest getting your input separately because it will greatly reduce the complexity of your code.

The problem you're facing is that all your inputs are **treated at once** when writing `34+56` and **treated 3 times** when read separately like in `34 + 56` (because of the space).

Therefore, what you need to do is read the whole line:

```
std::cout << "Please enter a calculation:";
std::string str;
std::getline (std::cin, str);
```

Then, you need to locate the sign and split your string there:

```
// "34+56"
std::size_t index = str.find_first_of("+-/*");    // returns the index 2
std::string operand1 = str.substr(0, index);      // "34"
std::string operand2 = str.substr(index + 1);     // "56"
```

Finally, you can output an

> Error message for a number that has 2 digits or more and have only one digit in the variables val1 and val2.

```
// converts string -> int
int val1 = atoi(operand1.c_str());
int val2 = atoi(operand1.c_str());

// check if in range
if( (val1<0||val1>9) || (val2<0||val2>9) ) {
    std::cout << "Operand must be between 0 and 10!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Using first digit of operands..."  << std::endl;

    //Edit(wrong operation): Use the leftmost character minus character '0'
    val1 = operand1[0] - '0';  
    val2 = operand2[0] - '0'; 
}
```

**Notes:** I did not actually test this. There are many cases where this will fail(**i.e** there is more than one operation). You could also argue that finding the first valid character and saving it is more efficient, but I find extracting the whole operands into strings cleaner.

Comment: The modulo operator evaluates to the remainder of the left operand divided by the right, but the op seems to want the left most digit of `val` 1 & 2.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it like this:

```
while(true) {
    cout << "Please enter a calculation (operand operator operand):" << endl;
    while(true) {
        cin >> val1 >> op >> val2;
        if((val1<0||val1>9)||(val2<0||val2>9)) {
            cout << "Wrong input!  Try again." << endl;
            break;
        }
        cout << "val1: " << val1 << "  val2: " << val2 << endl;
    }
}
```

Seems like the most obvious solution.  Thxalot!!